# Convert string to Image from SAP

Tags: c#, image, .net-core

I have a micro service in .Net Core 3.1 WebApi which's job it is to get fetch images from a SAP oData endpoint and convert it to an image that an app can use.
But i have some trouble being able to return the image. The process of getting the image works. But converting it from the SAP format([Example found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3d5gjrhdz09miel/response.json?dl=0)).
The code for converting sort of works, but it only returns this:

```
{
    "tag": null,
    "physicalDimension": {
        "isEmpty": false,
        "width": 3456,
        "height": 2304
    },
    "size": {
        "isEmpty": false,
        "width": 3456,
        "height": 2304
    },
    "width": 3456,
    "height": 2304,
    "horizontalResolution": 0,
    "verticalResolution": 0,
    "flags": 73744,
    "rawFormat": {
        "guid": "b96b3cae-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e"
    },
    "pixelFormat": "Format24bppRgb",
    "frameDimensionsList": [
        "7462dc86-6180-4c7e-8e3f-ee7333a7a483"
    ],
    "palette": {
        "flags": 0,
        "entries": []
    },
    "propertyIdList": [],
    "propertyItems": []
}
```

The code looks like this:

```
byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(imageSet.Data);
                await using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer)
                {
                    Position = 0
                };

                var bmpReturn = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

                memoryStream.Close();
                return bmpReturn;
```

Almost all examples i have found is with a existing image on the server. I only have the raw data. How can i convert it to something a webpage or app can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you want to have an action method that will return an image from memory. You almost have it working, you shouldn't need to play with MemoryStream.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    // code to fetch imageSet

    byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(imageSet.Data);        
    return File(b, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Then, you just use this as a regular image url:

```
<img src="path to your action method" />
```